# Install Elementary's desktop on Bash for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-windows

I'm using [this open source](https://github.com/NathanCastle/BootShellCredentialProvider) to boot to a linux desktop straight from my Windows LogonUI, using the WSL.
My preferred linux desktop is of course elementary.
How do I install elementary's desktop on my ubuntu bash on Windows?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do ... but I have a question ... why have you not mentioned virtualation? perhaps under virtualbox running elementary linux loki

Answer (score 2):

You should try to install the `elementary-desktop` package

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: and what binary do I need to run?

Comment: You should run the commands here in a terminal window first once.
After you can start a new Pantheon shell with `gnome-session --session=pantheon`